# Serverless: Not all typescript files compiled within the same directory

Tags: typescript, serverless-framework

The weirdest thing is happening. I’m using typescript and not all my typescript files within a single directory are getting compiled, i.e. there’s one directory in my source tree where a few of the .ts files are being compiled to .js and the others aren’t.

When I run a simple tsc, all files are compiled, but when I run ‘serverless offline start’, not all files are compiled.

Anybody know how to fix?

Basics of my serverless.yml:

```
package:
  include:
    - src/**/*

functions:
  graphql:
    handler: src/graphql.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: post
          cors: true

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es2016", /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs", /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "removeComments": true, /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true, /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "strictNullChecks": true, /* Enable strict null checks. */
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false, /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    "noUnusedLocals": true, /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    "noUnusedParameters": false, /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    "moduleResolution": "node", /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "esModuleInterop": true, /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "experimentalDecorators": true, /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "types": [
    "typePatches",
    "nodes"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but according to the docs, `outDir` and `rootDir` can not be overwritten. All outputted code is going to `.build` directory regardless.

Comment: Thanks Deev, I tried commenting out `outDir` and `rootDir` and it didn't make a difference, but thanks for the suggestion! Again, for anybody else who might be reading, some `.ts` files are compiling and some aren't.

Answer (score 6):

`serverless-plugin-typescript` plugin compiles ts only starting from root files taken from severless functions handlers, in your case src/graphql.handler, and root file src/graphql.ts. All files not referenced in the dependencies chain are ignored.

serverless `package.include` options just additionally copies speficied locations without ts compilation.

So, if you miss some file in .build directory, make sure you import it somewhere in handler. I faced to similar issues when some lib dynamically loaded files from configured globs like `./some_dir/*.ts` (as I remember typeorm entities or migrations). Solution was to make `./some_dir/index.ts` and export all files in this dir. Then just `import * as all_some_dir from './some_dir'` in your handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, if the file is not referenced, it will not get picked up.